# Pygame starts from the place where the game ended

Tags: python, pygame

After game over , when I start the game again it starts from the same position.
Press Backspace to exit push mode (so that you can move up and dwon too).

```
import pygame, sys


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game_over = False



# Player Class


class Player:


    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)
        self.color = (250, 120, 60)
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.up_pressed = False
        self.down_pressed = False
        self.speed = 6

        self.trail = []

        self.running = False


    def  main(self):
        self.update()
        self.check_collisons()
        self.draw()
        sparc.main()
       
    def draw(self):
        global win
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)
        
        pygame.draw.rect(win,(sparc.color), sparc.Rect)



    def check_collisons(self):
        if self.x >= 760:
            self.x = 760
        elif self.x <= 0 :
            self.x = 0
        if self.y >=570:
            self.y = 570
        elif self.y<=0:
            self.y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0

        if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
            self.velX = -self.speed
        if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
                self.velX = self.speed
        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed :
             self.velY = -self.speed
        if self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed :
            self.velY = self.speed

        self.x += self.velX
        self.y += self.velY

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)
        pos = self.rect.midbottom
        if self.trail:
            if self.trail[-1] != pos:
                self.trail.append(pos)
        else:
            self.trail = [pos, pos]

    def push(self):
        global win,player,game_over
        game_over = False
        win.fill((255, 255, 255, 0))
        self.y = 570

        while self.running == False and game_over==False:


            for event in  pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        self.left_pressed = True
                    if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        self.right_pressed = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        self.running = True
                        main_game()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player.left_pressed = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.right_pressed = False


            win.fill((12, 24, 36))

            player.main()
            pygame.draw.lines(win, (player.color), False, player.trail, 2)




            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)






class Sparc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = WIDTH-40
        self.y = HEIGHT-40
        self.color = (255,255,255)
        self.Rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y, 30,30)
        self.velx = 2
        self.vely = 3




    def move(self):
        if self.Rect.y==HEIGHT-40:
            self.Rect.x -= self.velx
        if self.Rect.x<=5:
            self.Rect.x = 5
            self.Rect.y -=self.vely
        if self.Rect.y<=5:
            self.Rect.y = 5
            self.Rect.x +=self.velx
        if self.Rect.x>=WIDTH-40:
            self.Rect.x = WIDTH-40
            self.Rect.y+= self.vely







    def check_collisons(self):
        if self.Rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            you_lost()
    def main(self):

        self.check_collisons()
        self.move()





player = Player(WIDTH / 2, 570)
sparc = Sparc()


def main_game():

    while player.running==  True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.left_pressed = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.right_pressed = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     player.up_pressed = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.down_pressed = True
                if player.y >= 560:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        player.running = False
                        player.push()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.left_pressed = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.right_pressed = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.up_pressed = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.down_pressed = False
        win.fill((12, 24, 36))
        player.main()
        pygame.draw.lines(win, (player.color), False, player.trail, 2)
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()


def you_lost():
    global game_over
    game_over = True
    while game_over == True:
        win.fill((120, 24, 36))
        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
        text = font.render('GAME OVER', True, ((255, 100, 0)))
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT// 2)
        win.blit(text,textRect)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                     pass

                    

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


player.push()
```

Is there any way to restart it?
When I press enter, after game over it all restarts.
And I'm trying to build something like this -- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vAxbIKjbq8HRnjbAAUOffyH3efynjbXM/view?usp=sharing

If you can built a function which fills the the area between the trails (you can see the docx for better explanation) then please put it in the answer.

Comment: The main problem with this game is that you call your game functions recursively. Where did you see such an approach? It will never work properly. To reset the game, write a function that initializes all game states. Call the function once at startup and call it again if you want to reset the game.

Comment: What do you mean by a function which intializes all game states?? Can you explain it with an example??

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to create the variable to store the status. then you can come back with that status when you ended the game.

Comment: Is there to just undo changes done by me?

Comment: i tried to run your game. but it said 'NameError: name 'qix' is not defined'

Comment: Just delete anything with qix. It was a class I deleted to make the code simpler.